# My join table in a mySQL database is failing to populate with data from my Spring Application

Tags: mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I'm creating a Spring Application that will allow users to search neighbourhoods and their ratings based on Google's Places and Maps API. I have included a function that will allow the user to click a button and save the latitude, longitude, address and ratings of the current location searched to their profile. They can save as many areas as they wish. For now, I'm attempting to pass only a String address, a double latitude and double longitude and will worry about ratings when I get it working correctly.

In order to do this, I created a join table between a User object and Area object in the User entity.

```
private List<Area> savedAreas;
.....
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_area", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "area_id"))
public List<Area> getSavedAreas() {
    return savedAreas;
}

public void setSavedAreas(List<Area> savedAreas) {
    this.savedAreas = savedAreas;
}
```

I attempt to add an area object to the currently logged in user via the following method in the User entity class that I will call later in the controller class.

```
public void addArea(Area area) {
    savedAreas.add(area);
}
```

The join table shows up in the MySQL prompt but returns an 'empty set(0.00sec)'

The save button from the client side will call the following method in the controller class that will receive the data passed from an Ajax query from the client side and store it into variables.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAreaToProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveAreaToProfile(Area area, @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") double longitude, 
        @RequestParam("areaName") String areaName) {

      // This is a way of authenicating the current user to create a session 
      Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String username = loggedInUser.getName(); 

      User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);


      // Saving the area to the db before I save it to the join table
      areaRepository.save(area);
      // Attempting to save the area to the user's area list which should, in theory, populate the join table?
      user.addArea(area);

      return "/";
}
```

I have excluded a number of `System.out.println()` debuggers for conciseness which print the data values in the eclipse console to ensure everything is working correctly. The latitude, longitude, address variables, as well as the authenticated username and area saved to the db are all printing correctly. The only issue is the join table between the area and user returning an empty set?

Comment: did you try saving the user too?

Comment: Hi Jorge, the user gets saved when they register, they will then be logged in. The authentication in the `saveAreaToProfile()` method in the controller then confirms the logged in user as the user object that wishes to save the area object to its profile.

Comment: I mean, you need to update the user after each area object added, you are seeking a logged user and adding their areas but you aren't saving the user again.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thank you Jorge!